# how do i send a message to a ActiveMQ using JMS Sender in wso2esb

Tags: wso2, activemq-classic, wso2-esb

How to set an endpoint to push a data to ActiveMQ using JMS Sender. When I gave endpoint as jms:/sampleQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.
activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://dev.messagebroker.yenlo.local:61616&
transport.jms.DestinationType=queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send a message to ActiveMQ you should set the URL in below format.

```
jms:/sampleQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue
```

When entering the above URLs in the management console, replace `&` character in the endpoint URL with `&amp;`

for more https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/ESB+as+a+JMS+Producer

Comment: but was throwing error invalid http/https protocols.

Comment: hi Rajjaz, Thanks for the reply.When I gave it throw "Invalid" http/https protocols. Can I give http://localhost:8280/services/sampleQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue.

Comment: hi Rajjaz, Last comment was wrong url mentioned. Thanks for the reply.When I gave it throw "Invalid" http/https protocols. Can I give http:/sampleQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:8161&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue.

Comment: you should start the URL with jms:/sampleQueue(queue name)

Comment: Hi Rajjaz, its giving me "Test address only supported for HTTP and HTTPS protocols"

Comment: When i try for <address uri="jms:/SampleQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://Hostname:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue">   and when i click Test btn It gives me "Test address only supported for HTTP and HTTPS protocols". In transport i hav gvn transport="jms". As mentioned in Docs I have uncommented in axis2.xml (ActiveMQ). So how to resolve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Ashwin,Can you share your proxy?

Comment: Hi, This is my proxy

Comment: <proxy><target> <inSequence><log><property expression="json-eval($.)"name="data"/>  </log><send><endpoint ><address uri="jms:/demo?transport.jms.Conn ectionFactoryJNDINam‌​e=QueueConnectionFac‌​tory&amp;java. naming‌​.factory.initial=org‌​.apache.activemq.jnd‌​i.ActiveMQInitialCon‌​textFactory &amp;java‌​.naming.provider.url‌​=tcp://Hostname:6161‌​6&amp;transport. jms.‌​DestinationType=queu‌​e"/></endpoint></send></inSequence></target></proxy>

Comment: <proxy xmlns= http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse name="demo" startOnLoad="true" statistics="disable" trace="disable" transports="jms"> I am new to this. i have gvn http:// ok before ws.apache

Comment: Hi Ashwin, can you change your hostname. it's mentioned as Hostname so try to change as localhost and let me know.

Comment: Still the same. I hav gvn jms:/sampleQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue.                                                              
gave me "Test address only supported for HTTP and HTTPS protocols"

Comment: Hi Rajjaz, It worked. Without testing(click for Test btn) the URL worked. It was my mistake. I was checking for that url ie I type URL and click Test button and it gave me Invalid HTTP/HTTPS protocols. But now I just gave url and saved it and Tested the proxy. It is logging to the Queue. Thanks Rajjaz

Comment: Rajjaz,Can u tell me how to fetch the message which we logged in queue also too

Comment: hi Rajjaz any updates I tried to fetch data from the same queue by just giving log mediator in out sequence so that we can capture response. But it gives me  "WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-6"